# How does SO get its Tag dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, stack-overflow

How does stackoverflow loads its available tags on the tag input below when you are asking a question? do they populate the available tags when the page loads or they make a request per user input or user key press? I am planning to implement the same way in my application but I have no idea on how will I achieve this thing.

Comment: A good place to start would be to search the web for "javascript ajax autocomplete"

Comment: If you want to investigate install firebug (for Firefox) or simmilar addon and analyze browser requests and server responses in Net tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They *definitely* do not load all available tags on page load, as there are way too many.  I ran a quick test under the web console in Firefox, and it appears they do a JSON request using AJAX.  An example would be:

https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=visual&newstyle=true&_=1359502308905

Which results the response:

```
[{"Name":"c#","Synonyms":"visual-c#","Count":409187,"Excerpt":"C# is a multi-paradigm programming language encompassing strong typing, imperative, declarative, functional, generic, object-oriented (class-based), and component-oriented programming disciplines. It was developed by Microsoft for use with their .NET framework and later approved as a standard by Ecma (ECMA-334) and ISO (ISO/IEC 23270:2006). It is now also available on different platforms (Android, Linux, iOS) via the MONO project."},{"Name":"visual-studio-2010","Synonyms":"visual-studio-2010-rtm","Count":30434,"Excerpt":"Visual Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE) from Microsoft."},{"Name":"visual-studio","Synonyms":"visualstudio","Count":25157,"Excerpt":"Visual Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE) from Microsoft. It supports many different programming languages."},{"Name":"visual-studio-2008","Synonyms":"visualstudio2008","Count":13539,"Excerpt":"This tag refers to the Visual Studio line of software development products from Microsoft, the 2008 version."},{"Name":"visual-c++","Synonyms":"visualc++","Count":12298,"Excerpt":"Microsoft Visual C++ is a C and C++ compiler for Windows. The most recent version of the compiler is Visual C++ 2012, which is available in both commercial editions and in a free Express Edition.\r\n\r\nThe compiler supports the following languages:\r\n\r\n\r\nC: Only the C90 standard is supported; there is very limited C99 support\r\nC++: Also includes support for several major C++11 features as of Visual Studio 2010\r\nC++/CLI and .NET Managed Extensions for C++"},{"Name":"vba","Synonyms":"visual-basic-applications","Count":12195,"Excerpt":"Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) is an event-driven programming language which was first introduced by Microsoft in 1993 to give Excel 5.0 a more robust object-oriented language for writing macros and automating the use of Excel.  It is now used for the entire Office suite. If your question is specifically about programming Excel, Access, Word or Outlook, use the appropriate tag: excel-vba, access-vba, word-vba or outlook-vba."}]
```

They also seem to lag a bit, so they're not firing off too many HTTP requests at once.  You have to stop typing for a second or two before it does the request.

Comment: is it a bad practice to load all tags?

Comment: It would say it could *potentially* be a performance impact, depending on the number of tags you had.  If you had 20-30 tags, you could hard code them into a `.js` file that would get cached by the browser.  I think StackOverflow has thousands.

Comment: But what if I get the tags from the database itself?

Comment: If it were me, I'd use an approach similar to StackOverflow (grab tag data on the fly with AJAX).  It's more flexible and you don't need to worry about getting too many tags in the future.

Comment: that being said do you have any references on how would I Do that? like maybe getting the query results from the database as json response and then outputting it ? or somehow the same implementation as SO Does?

Comment: Implementation of such a system would be out of scope for a StackOverflow question.  I suggest you give it a shot, and post a new question if and when you run into trouble.  Good luck!